# Only close first fold when file is opened

Tags: vimrc, folding

When I open a file, I want to automatically fold all outer most folds, so no nesting. Here is what I currently have in my config:

```
set fdm=syntax
set foldnestmax=20
set foldenable
" set foldlevel=99
set foldlevelstart=1
```

This opens files with all folds closed recursively, when I set the foldlevelstart higher it closes only the inner folds.